# Why does the output delivery system fail to select the output I specify?

Tags: sas

I have a short piece of SAS 9.3 code that outputs some Chi-squared statistics. I'm using `ods select ChiSq` to select only the tables of output I need, but SAS returns this warning:

> WARNING: Output 'ChiSq' was not created.  Make sure that the output
>   object name, label, or path is spelled correctly.  Also, verify that
>   the appropriate procedure options are used to produce the requested
>   output object.  For example, verify that the NOPRINT option is not
>   used.

This is the code:

```
ods html;

data flu;
input gender treatmentcourse improvement;
datalines;
012
000
110
112
002
002
012
000
000
012
111
011
002
101
002
011
100
100
001
110
110
011
001
010
101
001
000
001
110
100
;

proc format;
value treatmentformat 0 = "minor"
                      1 = "minor"
                      2 = "major";

ods trace on;
ods select ChiSq;
proc freq data = flu order = data;
tables treatmentcourse * improvement /chisq cmh;
format treatmentcourse treatmentformat.;
run;
ods trace off;
ods select all;
ods html close;
```

I can clearly see as a result of `ods trace on;` that the `ChiSq` table is included in the output, but SAS ignores the `ods select` statement and displays all the tables.

In the datalines, the first colum is gender, 0 for males and 1 for females. The second column is 0 if the patient took the drug and 1 if the patient took the placebo. The third column is a scale of 0 - 2, 0 being no improvement in flu symptoms and 2 being much improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you put your custom format on the wrong variable.  Try this instead:

```
proc freq data = flu order = data;
   tables treatmentcourse * improvement /chisq cmh;
   format improvement treatmentformat.;
run;
```

If you look at your log more carefully, you should see a SAS NOTE that no statistics were created.

UPDATE: You also should put a `run;` statement after your `proc format` step, just to be safe.